# C++ Stdlib IO Implementation details

Tags: c++, io, implementation, std

1. Are there any guarantees that C++ std IO will be portable across all Desktop and Mobile OS (I'm interested in iOS and Android)?
2. Is implementation of std IO different across the platforms or it is rather uniform? If it is different, then does it happen due to SDK of the platform (in other words - do SDK's provide those different implementations)?
3. Who provide those implementation? Who is the author? Does anybody update them?
4. Where is documentation?

Comment: the std library usually ships with the compiler package.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any guarantees that C++ std
>   IO will be portable across all Desktop
>   and Mobile OS (I'm interested in iOS
>   and Android)?

No, there are no guarantees that these platforms will implement, correctly at all the standard library.

> Is implementation of std IO different
>   across the platforms or it is rather
>   uniform? If it is different, then does
>   it happen due to SDK of the platform
>   (in other words - do SDK's provide
>   those different implementations)?

It's different. I/O is very different on different platforms.

> Who provide those implementation? Who
>   is the author? Does anybody update
>   them? Where is documentation?

Either the compiler implementor or the platform owner provides them. The C++ Standard describes what the library must do.

Comment: @Haroogan I meant to say what I said.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are failing to see the power of the standard libraries. They are designed to provide a common set of functionality that is available across any standards compliant compiler. For example, if I write the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int a, char** s)
{
  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This will be compiled by *any* standards compliant compiler. You're getting hung up on, well the way `std::cout` works is different on each platform - yes of course it is. But this is the beauty of it - why do you have to care? On windows, if you compile this with MS Visual C++, that compiler will have the correct implementation (which the standard doesn't care about) to support the above *standard way* of writing to standard out. Similarly, on Linux GCC will have the correct code to write to whatever implementation, and on Solaris, CC will do the same.

You don't have to worry or frankly care. The handling for your platform is provided by the compiler that you are using for that platform. You have a nice clean high-level interface to work with.

Do you care how the Java VM handles the details of each platform? You don't, it's not your concern, you know when you do `System.out.println()` it will be written to the screen (or whatever for that VM) appropriately. SO why are you getting hung up on this?

The thing you have understand is whether the compiler that you are using on the specific platform will provide all the functionality in the standard library (i.e. is it fully standards compliant or not) and if not, what's missing and how to work around it. The rest is frankly irrelevant!

As for if you don't like it, well pay for something like Roguewave - which frankly is pissing money away, but it's your money to piss away...

Answer (score 2):

Standard library is exactly that — standard. It's defined by standard. Every standard-compliant compiler must provide it. So the guarantee is that it will be portable across standard-compliant implementations (whether there's one for your target platform is a whole different question altogether). It has nothing to do with platform SDKs (whether it's implemented using one doesn't matter — the observable behaviour must be the same).

Comment: To implement reading from file - you have to be able to interact with underlying file system, which is absolutely different across different platforms. Therefore I think that implementations should vary with the platform, but I can be wrong. When you say standard - is standard - you are trying to mask the answer. I need the direct answers.

Comment: @Haroogan: No, that's the whole point of abstracted stream interface. File paths will be platform-specific, but the access to the file itself *will not*. The implementation does *not* matter, you're dealing with an abstract interface that has well-defined behaviour.

Comment: I don't like stdlib's interface. Are there any other interfaces?

Comment: @Haroogan You don't like an interface designed by people far smarter than you (or me) to do an extremely difficult job and do it well? I predict you are not going to do well in the software development field with an attitude like that.

Comment: Keep your subjective opinion about my skills. Now to clarify - it is their own business for doing this. Nor you nor me asked them to do it. Right now I'm not talking about underlying implementations - that's great. Currently I'm speaking about interface design. It hasn't been updated for years and looks quit old. Chosen design patterns are wrong in terms of OOP and mixed with C as far as I can see, because the developers seemed to be lazy to design for a new C++ language and decided to create this bloating mix. Therefore coding with stdlib looks messy. Is there any alternative?

Comment: OOP and stdlib? what possibly benefit stdlib would have from OOP? OOP memcpy? OOP qsort? OOP fopen? there's no benefit from OOP in simple functions that you can find in stdlib

Comment: Oh man... We are currently talking about IO! For instance stream classes - they look awful.

Comment: @fazo: Well, C standard library sucks so much nothing can help it. ;)

Comment: @Haroogan: What is so awful about stream classes?

Comment: @Haroogan Well why not turn your genius to a better design? However, the stream classes look the way they do for very good reasons, and nobody has been able to come up with a better solution.

Comment: That's why I'm asking these questions. It seems nobody is going to make it modern and up to date! Nobody is developing it. It was left to die in it's own mess. Considering extremely broad usage of C++, its popularity and effectiveness, it still relies on a junky libraries with tatty interfaces - really, what a shame...

Comment: Neil - nobody tried to come up with other solution. It was enough for them that they have made it working and stable inside, and that's all. I understand that nobody will pay for this and that's why REVISION of the whole STDLIB is not likely to happen in the nearest future. Therefore, users will have to use this junk, because there are no alternatives and that's sad. IMO such basic things like standard libraries need refreshments from time to time.

Comment: @Haroogan: You still haven't said what is wrong with it. You are also free to use Boost.IOStreams, or any other I/O library.

Comment: @Haroogan I see from your other posts, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110438/stdlib-and-io-routines-in-c that you are in fact a troll. Goodbye.

Comment: Bye Neil. BTW Cat Plus Plus, I was wondering if Boost's IO is portable? I've seen people have problems with it on mobile platforms.

Comment: @Haroogan: I don't know, I don't care about mobile platforms at all. Research it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a standard (hence the std) is that it is respected and uniform no matter what platform you are on.
Some developers ship devices with support for all or some of the std library, it's really just up to them how it is implemented.

This is platform specific and probably available in each platform's SDK documentation, available most probably with the SDK or on the vendor's website.

Comment: You say it is standard, how can documentation be platform specific then?

Comment: Some platforms don't implement all of the standard library. I am currently working on a platform where certain functions are missing, and so this is described in a document given by the vendor.